# Return common node between 2 different queries

Tags: neo4j

I want to find out the common node between 2 different queries. I am trying hard to find out, but could not think of a solution. My motive is to collect top 5 out-degree nodes, collect top 5 root nodes, and return nodes that are common between top 5 outdegree and root nodes. I don't know how to merge the results because after using "return" option in the first query, no further statements would be executed, but without "return" option we cannot collect results. (Please do correct me, if I am thinking wrong). Following are the queries,

```
// for root nodes
match (u:Port1)<-[r]-(root)
where not((root)<--())
return distinct(root.id) as Node, count(r) as Outdegree
ORDER BY count(r) desc limit 5

//for outdegree nodes
match (n:Port1)-[r]->()
return n.id as Node, count(r) as Outdegree
order by Outdegree DESC
union
match (a:Port1)-[r]->(leaf)
where not((leaf)-->())
return leaf.id as Node, 0 as Outdegree limit 5
```

How should I combine both results, and get the output of a list of nodes that are common? Please do help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the intersection between the two, you don't even need unions. Just collect the top 5 in both cases and find the intersection.

[APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions) can help here. Something like:

```
// for root nodes
match (:Port1)<-[r]-(root)
where not((root)<--())
// no need for distinct since you're aggregating
with root, count(r) as Outdegree
ORDER BY Outdegree desc limit 5
with collect(root) as rootNodes // back to a single row

//for outdegree nodes
match (n:Port1)
// more efficient way to get out degree without needing to expand
with rootNodes, n, size((n)-->()) as Outdegree
order by Outdegree DESC limit 5

with rootNodes, collect(n) as outdegreeNodes
with apoc.coll.intersection(rootNodes, outdegreeNodes) as commonNodes

// if needed, unwind and get outdegree
unwind commonNodes as commonNode
return commonNode.id as Node, size((commonNode)-->()) as Outdegree
```

Comment: This code works fine for all networks, except for 1 network. In 4th network of mine, first 5 out-degree nodes are [93,99,97,156,98], and first 5 root nodes are [73,1,79,76,120]. When I run the above code, I get "1" as the answer, where it is not the common node between the 2 operations. Should I add any further code?

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Can you confirm by replacing everything below the intersection call with this: `return [node in commonNodes | node.id] as commonNodeIds, [node in rootNodes | node.id] as rootNodeIds, [node in outdegreeNodes | node.id] as outdegreeNodeIds`

Comment: I have replaced this code `// if needed, unwind and get outdegree unwind commonNodes as commonNode
return commonNode.id as Node, size((commonNode)-->()) as Outdegree ` with your code. And I get "Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError", wherein the error statement is "Variable `rootNodes` not defined (line 14, column 67 (offset: 450))

"return [node in commonNodes | node.id] as commonNodeIds, [node in rootNodes | node.id] as rootNodeIds, [node in outdegreeNodes | node.id] as outdegreeNodeIds". It says "rootNodes" are not defined.

Comment: That's my mistake, forgot to keep those in scope in the WITH. With the current changes, replace the line with the intersection call with: `with rootNodes, outdegreeNodes, apoc.coll.intersection(rootNodes, outdegreeNodes) as commonNodes`